# C# - How to fail compilation if some method has attribute A but doesn't have attribute B?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

How to fail compilation if only one of the following attributes is being used?

```
    public class Attribute1 : Attribute {}
    public class Attribute2 : Attribute {}

    [Attribute1()]
    [Attribute2()]
    public void SomeMethod()
    {

    }
```

If a method has 'Attribute1' attribute - it must having 'Attribute2' attribute an vice versa. Otherwise compile should be failed with proper message.

Comment: Attributes are runtime behaviour, not compile time. If you really need to has this sort of behaviour, then you should use a single attribute that contains both sets of functionality.

Comment: The underlying question is why you want to force the classes to have certain attributes. What do they contain, and why do the classes need them? There are ways to require classes to have certain properties or methods or get a compiler error. I suspect that if you describe what you want to do with the attributes there will be a solution along those lines. Attributes aren't meant to be required.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to write is [code analyzer](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Getting-Started-Writing-a-Custom-Analyzer-&-Code-Fix), and hook it into your [msbuild files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-project-file-schema-reference), then pack these build targets to [nuget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec) if you want to publish your library.

Answer (score -1):

You can `Reflections in C#` for this purpose. ([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection))

MSDN Description of Reflection

> You can use reflection to dynamically create an instance of a type, bind the type to an existing object, or get the type from an existing object and invoke its methods or access its fields and properties. **If you are using attributes in your code, reflection enables you to access them**.

Use the below code to access the attributes in your code

```
try
    {
        // Get the type of MyClass1.
        Type myType = typeof(MyClass1);
        // Get the members associated with MyClass1.
        MemberInfo[] myMembers = myType.GetMembers();

        // Display the attributes for each of the members of MyClass1.
        for(int i = 0; i < myMembers.Length; i++)
        {
            Object[] myAttributes = myMembers[i].GetCustomAttributes(true);
            if(myAttributes.Length > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nThe attributes for the member {0} are: \n", myMembers[i]);
                for(int j = 0; j < myAttributes.Length; j++)
                    Console.WriteLine("The type of the attribute is {0}.", myAttributes[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", e.Message);
    }
```

Then after getting all the `attributes` associated with your `class` proceed with your requirements, otherwise if you don't have both `attributes` then throw an `exception`.